# Translate window function into DAX

Tags: dax

i have a logic within a stored procedure that I'd like to translate into DAX.
Since i am rather new and I am probably searching with the wrong keywords, i cannot figure out how to transform this windowing function into propper dax.

```
select FIRST_VALUE(v) OVER(PARTITION BY partid ORDER BY somedate DESC, somenumber DESC) as myval
FROM table1
```

The query takes the first value of a group flagged wit hthe same partid (respecting the descending order of first somedate and then somenumber).

Can you please hint me into the right direction?

Comment: Can you give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of input and expected output? It's much easier to answer concretely than abstractly.

Answer (score 0):

The following would give you one value based on the highest somedate and somenumber. If you bring in the someid as a slicer then you should get what you're looking for.

```
=
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table'[Column] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        [somedate] = CALCULATE ( MAX ( [somedate] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )
    ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        [somedate] = CALCULATE ( MAX ( [somenumber] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )
    )
)
```